# Can I reliably expect cheesecake to raise by 10°F after being taken out of the oven?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, cheesecake

I just made a Pumpkin cheesecake. Long story short, I tried substituting whipping cream for condensed milk, in equal parts, and my cake ended up super watery.

I managed to get the temperature to 155°F, and by the look of the surface, it was definitely done, so I took it out. I cooked it to 155°F because everywhere I looked, that seemed to be the agreed upon temperature. Even this cooking

I used to cook my cheesecakes to 165°F at least, because I liked the thick crust that that gave it, even if it was a little drier.

Now that I'm cooking "lighter" cheesecakes though, I have to wonder, is 155°F safe? The recipe contains raw eggs, which should be cooked to ideally 165°F. That means, it must be the expectation that the temperature will rise by 5-10°F internally.

Can I reliably expect a cheesecake to raise to a safe temperature after being taken out of the oven?

Comment: FYI - according to the FDA, dishes that contain eggs only need to reach 160F.

Comment: @DebbieM. [Health Canada's guide is a little bit stricter](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/meat-poultry-fish-seafood-safety/eggs.html#a5)

Comment: Are you measuring the internal temperature at the deepest part of the cheesecake? If so, I would be quite certain the internal temperature would raise an additional 10 degrees after it is taken out while resting, especially if you leave it in the tin it was cooked in. Second, the dangerous organisms in such dishes start dying very quickly once you hit 150. At 165 they die instantly, but at 150 they die within seconds.

Comment: @Behacad Yes. Using a digital thermometer straight into the middle until I could feel the crust. And ok, good to know. I'm asking because my 85 year old Grandma may have some, and I'd like to not take any chances.